# Multiprocessing Pandas eats memory

Tags: python, pandas, memory, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm using multiprocessing to try to speed up the processing of about 1000 ~500MB csv files using Pandas. I'm trying to apply a simple string regex to one column. The program works, but it seems to not free memory properly, and it eventually comes to eat up 40-80GB per process, despite none of the files being over 10GB. Do you have any idea why this could be? I've tried a number of ways to clear memory, to no avail.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import multiprocessing
import gc
from ctypes import cdll, CDLL
from random import shuffle

oldc = ""
newc = ""

NUMPROC = 8
rep = None

cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")

def main(filename, oldcol, newcol):
    global oldc 
    global newc 
    global rep
    names = np.empty([1,1])
    oldc = oldcol
    newc = newcol
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    names = df.as_matrix()
    del df
    rep = {}
    rep[newc] = {}
    for row in names[1:]:
        oldname = r"^"+str(row[0])+r"( .*|$)"
        newname = str(row[1]) + r"\1"
        rep[newc][oldname]=newname
    if not os.path.exists("./standardized/"):
        print("Making dir!")
        os.makedirs("./standardized/")
    files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if (os.path.isfile(f) and ".csv" in f and not (f==filename or "household" in str(f) or os.path.exists("./standardized/"+f[:-4]+"_stnd.csv")))]
    shuffle(files)
    allfiles = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if ".csv" in f]
    for f in allfiles:
         if os.path.exists("./standardized/"+f[:-4]+"_stnd.csv"):
             if os.path.getsize(f) > os.path.getsize("./standardized/"+f[:-4]+"_stnd.csv"):
                files.append(f)
    print(len(files))
    bundle = [(idx, f) for idx, f in enumerate(files)]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=NUMPROC, maxtasksperchild=1)
    r = pool.map_async(process, bundle)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()



def process(bundle):
    global oldc
    global rep
    global newc
    fname = bundle[1]
    idx = bundle[0]
    try:
        print(idx)
        libc.malloc_trim(0)
        curfile = pd.read_csv(fname, dtype="str")
        curfile[newc] = curfile[oldc].str.lower()
        curfile.replace(to_replace=rep, regex=True, inplace=True)
        curfile.to_csv("./standardized/"+fname[:-4]+"_stnd.csv")
        del curfile
    except:
        print("error on: " + str(fname))
    finally:
        gc.collect()
        libc.malloc_trim(0)






main("lookup.csv","namefrst","stndfrst")
```

Comment: "1000 ~500MB csv files" vs "none of the files being over 10GB" is a bit of a contradiction. How many of your files are that big? Having 8 10GB files in memory simultaneously would use a huge amount of memory.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! The files vary a lot. Most are around 500MB (this is the average), but a few are up to ~6GB. I have 512 GB of RAM (I have access to a large research server), but this program manages to take up all of it somehow...

Comment: So panda isn't good choice on large csv process. Why expand all variables if you have only a replace ? Pythonic way and pythonic cost, change your editing style !

Comment: You could try to ditch pandas and do your stuff with standard Python methods. After all you're not doing anything fancy that absolutely needs pandas.